# How to select img inside <a> tag with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

The html looks something like this:

```
            <ul id="nav">
            <li>
                <a class="parent">First Level<img class="right" src="gfx/arrow-news-slider-title.png"></a>

                <ul class="light">
                    <li class="full">
                        <a href="">Second Level</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="full">
                        <a href="">Third Level</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="full">
                        <a href="">...</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Here is the script so far:

```
        window['DropDown']  = {
       open: function(e){
        var dd = this;
        var a = $(e).children('a:first-child');
            $(e).children('ul').slideDown();
            $(a).unbind('click');
            $(a).bind('click',function(){dd.close(e)});

            $(e).addClass('open');

       },
       close:function(e){
        var dd = this;
        var a = $(e).children('a:first-child'); 
            $(e).children('ul').slideUp();
            $(a).unbind('click');
            $(a).bind('click',function(){dd.open(e)});

            $(e).removeClass('open');

       },
       init:function(){
            var dd = this;                                  
            $('#nav').find('li').each(function(){
                if($(this).find('ul').length > 0){          
                    var li = this;                          
                    var $li = $(this);                      
                    var a = $li.children('a:first-child')   
                    $(a).bind('click',function(){
                        dd.open(li);     
                    });
                }
            });

       }
    };
```

At the moment u can open all the "First Level's" by clicking anywhere in the li tag, but I would like to open them only if clicking the arrow-image. Does anyone have an Idea how to do this?

Comment: Sure, change `$li.children('a:first-child')` to target the image...

Comment: Sure, but I dont know how to select the right target. If i just put img into the parantheses it doesnt work

Comment: Add `" img"`(without quotes) after your existing selector to target the image inside the anchor you already selected. jquery selectors are almost identical to css.

Comment: It doesnt work, sorry! :(

Comment: Mark's answer has an example of what i was suggesting. you can leave the a:first-child, just add the img part.

Answer (score 1):

Something simple like this would work.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("a#YourLink img").event();
    });
</script>
```